# phpcpd, You need to set up the project dependencies using composer install

Tags: jenkins, composer-php

I've just installed phpcpd globally via following command:

```
sudo composer global require 'sebastian/phpcpd=
```

my ~/composer/vendor/bin/ directory is in my $PATH variable too.

Now when I try to run phpcpd I get following error:

```
You need to set up the project dependencies using the following commands:
wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar install
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point Sebastian didn't mention in the installation instructions is that by using Composer to globally install PHPCPD, you don't get it's dependencies installed, only the direct code. You have to go to the PHPCPD directory in the global vendor directory (i.e. the PHPCPD main folder in there, something like `...somepath/.composer/vendor/sebastian/phpcpd/`) and run `composer install` there.

The easier way would be to just install the `.phar` file, but I understand this has different issues.